# Cant create a new Servlet in IntelliJ Ultimate Edition 2023.2

Tags: intellij-idea, servlets, code-templates

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com) question, I cant create a Servlet file with the 'new' context menu `New -> Servlet`. However, as shown in the screenshot, `src/main/java` is alreay marked as a source root directory, so its a different problem than the answers suggest.Manually creating a Servlet from a javaclass works, however it would be nice to have the boilerplate code created automatically.

Im following this [text](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html#new_project) tutorial from JetBrains

[Screenshot showing the missing of 'new servlet'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23aOf.jpg)

[Screenshot showing the source root activation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmmmg.jpg)

I checked if the Sources root is set correctly and if the default servlet works correctly, which it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newest IntelliJ IDEA versions does not provide the default templates for creating servlets, listeners, and filters. However, you can define these templates yourself.

Paste the following code as the template body:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "${Class_Name}", value = "/${Class_Name}")
public class ${Class_Name} extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates`

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-configuring-web-application-elements.html#elements-templates for more information